# Is there a built-in way to respond with a HTTP message 200 and empty body?

Tags: http, go

I need to have a "check" HTTP endpoint that will just reply with a `200` code and empty body. The solution I have requires a separate function for that:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/rs/zerolog/log"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Use(mux.CORSMethodMiddleware(r))
    r.HandleFunc("/check", send200).Methods(http.MethodGet)
    err := http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:9991", r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic().Msgf("cannot start web server: %v", err)
    }
}

func send200(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    _, err := w.Write([]byte{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Error().Msgf("cannot send 200 answer → %v", err)
    }
}
```

It works as expected:

```
curl -v http://localhost:9991/check
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9991 (#0)
> GET /check HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9991
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 29 Oct 2021 12:11:06 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
```

Is there a simpler, possibly more Golangic way to handle `/check` as a one-liner directly at  the routing code?

Comment: Sure, skip the `Write`. `WriteHeader` will send the 200 response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an empty handler (a handler function whose body is empty: `{}`). If you write nothing to the response writer and set no status code, HTTP 200 OK will be sent back by default.

You may also use an anonymous function (function literal):

```
r.HandleFunc("/check", func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request){}).
    Methods(http.MethodGet)
```

Comment: Than you. The second part of your answer is clear but I am confused with the first one: what is an empty handler in that context?

Comment: @WoJ the answer shows an anonymous function literal with an *empty* body, i.e. `{}`. You could just as well write your named func as `func send200(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {}`, then register it as you did originally, and you'd get the same result.

Comment: @mkopriva: ah ok, clear. I thought that this was a specific handler, provided by Go, and that happens to be empty. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Go does not provide a handler that responds with a 200 status and an empty response body, but that's what happens when a handler does not call any of the [response writer](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter) methods.

If the handler does not call [WriteHeader](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter.WriteHeader), then the server responds with a 200 status code. Explicit calls to WriteHeader are primarily used to send error codes.

The response body is whatever the handler [writes](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter.Write) to the response. The response is empty if the handler does not write to the response.

Use an empty function to send the 200 response with an empty body:

```
send200 := func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {}
r.HandleFunc("/check", send200).Methods(http.MethodGet)
```